# Multiple & Hybrid Inheritance allowed in Apex?

Tags: apex

I should know this, but does Apex support multiple inheritance? I used to do it in C++. I 'm trying to model a class that looks like:

Mother -->kid <--- Father

Also what about hybrid? where the mother and father are derived from a single parent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Syntax for Apex is mostly based on Java and it does not allow multiple inheritance.

**[Hybrid](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/10/hybrid-inheritance-java-program/) (Not allowed)**

```
Virtual Class A
Virtual Class B extends A
Virtual Class C extends A
Class D extends B, C
```

**Multiple (Not allowed)**

```
Virtual Class A
Virtual CLass B
Class C extends A, B
```

**Multi level (Yes)**

```
Virtual class A
Virtual class B extends A
Class C extends B
```

Salesforce does allow multiple interface implementation.
To inherit any class, it must be defined with keyword `Virtual`.

[You can read more about inheritance here.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_defining.htm)

Comment: right- so it's like java where you can't do multiple inheritance per se, but you can do it with interfaces?

Comment: Yeah, Thats correct

Comment: how many levels salesforce support inheritance?

Comment: Prakash, your question made me curious and I wrote a script to generate classes extending each other in case the limit was high or weird behavior would come out at larger levels, but the limit is only 10.  If you go beyond that, you get:  Maximum type depth exceeded: 10

Comment: I'm having trouble do the multi level. Using the example you provided, I have a virtual method in class A that I need to extend in both B as well as C. But I am forced to use the virtual keyword for the method definition in B, so I cannot override it in C. any thoughts?

Edit: a minute after I said that, I tried using both virtual and override on the method definition and it seems to accept it. going to see if it actually works

Comment: Not able to use the above for my particular case. I'm trying to extend Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin and use the grandchild class from the Connected App - but it won't detect it.